# angular 2 NgIf hides ever, even observable will get from null to object

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-directives

I would like to show the something only if the user is logged in. The user is an `observable` and to show/hide I would like to use `NgIf`.

But the NgIf hides the content forever, even I see could verify the user changed from `null` to an `object`

```
userObserver: Observer<any>;
user: Observable<any>;

constructor() {
    this.user = new Observable((observer: Observer<string>) => {
        this.userObserver = observer;
    });

    this.user.subscribe((x) => {
        console.log('next', x);
    });
}

public login(credentials: ICredentials): Observable<any> {
    this.userObserver.next(credentials);
    return this.user;
}
```

In the template I use the observable like:

```
{{user | async | json}}                       // will change
<div *ngIf="user | async">user here</div>     // will never show up
```

**Edit**
I got it working using:

```
isLoginSubject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
user: Observable<any> = this.isLoginSubject.asObservable();
```

But then we can change the question to why? what difference makes it out?

Comment: is there routing to a new page involved after login and your subscribe is in that component?

Comment: @AJT_82 no routing involved. just using `ngIf` to show login form or logout button.